# Getting "unauthorized" errors when trying to use db.currentOp

Tags: mongodb

I want to create a user that can check the current operations before reading the data. I found that the way to do this would be to use db.currentOp(), which requires permissions to perform "inprog" action.

I have created `testRole` a role to achieve this

```
db.createRole({
    role: "testRole",
    privileges: [{
        resource: {
            db: "grtd",
            collection: ""
        },
        actions: ["inprog"]
    }],
    roles: []
})
```

And granted it to user grtdroot:

```
db.grantRolesToUser("grtdroot", "roles": [ {"role": "testRole", "db":"grtd"}])
```

However when I use `db.currentOp()` with user grtdroot I always get `{ "err" : "unauthorized" }`. I have confirmed that the roles are getting set correctly:

```
> db.getRoles({showPrivileges: true})
[
    {
        "role" : "testRole",
        "db" : "grtd",
        "isBuiltin" : false,
        "roles" : [ ],
        "inheritedRoles" : [ ],
        "privileges" : [
            {
                "resource" : {
                    "db" : "grtd",
                    "collection" : ""
                },
                "actions" : [
                    "inprog"
                ]
            }
        ],
        "inheritedPrivileges" : [
            {
                "resource" : {
                    "db" : "grtd",
                    "collection" : ""
                },
                "actions" : [
                    "inprog"
                ]
            }
        ]
    }
]
```

Am I missing something? Can't db.currentOp() be used on a user made database?

Also, if this is not the correct way to check concurrency, what would it be?

Comment: Where do you manage users/roles? in admin database or locally (grtd in your case)?

Comment: I manage roles locally. db is always "grtd"

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The docs for `inprog` say:

> Apply this action to the `cluster` resource.

From: http://docs.mongodb.org/manual/reference/privilege-actions/#authr.inprog

Also, I know when I assign the built-in `clusterMonitor` role, which contains the `inprog` action, I have to do it on the `admin` database rather than the database that the operations are going to be happening on.